# How to hook copy actions in windows

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard-hook

I know how to write and use windows hook DLLs to capture things such as window messages on a window.  What I need to do is capture any copy (Control+C or other method) done on the system in any application.  Is there a quick simple way to do this using windows hooks?

Comment: Are you after keyboard events, or clipboard events? They're two different things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the [SetClipboardViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Anytime the clipboard contents change, the most recent window to have been registered via this function (or the related [ChangeClipboardChain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) will receive a [WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

Its an applications responsibility to pass the message down the chain for to other registered viewers, as well as to un-register itself during shutdown.

This will be much more reliable than trying to hook <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd>.